# « 馬の耳に念仏 » littéralement : « adresser une prière à l'oreille d'un cheval »

Tags: expressions, japonais

Le proverbe japonais « 馬の耳に念仏 » se dit d'un ton sarcastique pour signifier que ça ne rime à rien de gaspiller sa salive à donner des conseils à une personne entêtée ou passer un savon à un enfant inattentif/rebelle –  tout comme il ne sert à rien d'adresser une prière à l'oreille d'un cheval qui ne sait pas parler notre langue !

Il faut dire que l'expression « donner de la confiture à des cochons » est un faux ami, car il s'agit là d'une chose précieuse *matérielle* donnée en pure perte à quelqu’un qui ne l’apprécie pas à sa juste valeur. Avec « 馬の耳に念仏 », en revanche, quelqu’un ne fait même pas semblant de retenir des conseils reçus.

Comment le dit-on en français ?

Comment: [_The horse whisperer_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Horse_Whisperer_(novel)), [_L'homme qui murmurait à l'oreille des chevaux_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Homme_qui_murmurait_%C3%A0_l%27oreille_des_chevaux_(roman)) serait le contre-exemple qui confirme la règle.

Answer (score 11):

Une expression assez proche sémantiquement parlant est :

> [**Parler à un mur**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parler_%C3%A0_un_mur).

On la rencontre souvent dans des phrases toute faites comme :

> Autant parler à un mur.
>
> J'ai l'impression de parler à un mur.
>
> Je préfère parler à un mur.

Answer (score 6):

Je vous demande par avance d'excuser la grossièreté de l'expression française que je veux proposer, mais en termes de sens, elle correspond tout-à-fait :

> **Pisser dans un violon** (perdre son temps dans une activité futile)
>
> Exemple en situation : *J'ai passé la matinée à essayer de lui faire entendre raison, mais il n'a rien voulu savoir ! Autant pisser dans un violon...*

([wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pisser_dans_un_violon))

Comment: Côté « grossièreté », est-ce que cette expression frôle la limite du supportable ? À tel point qu'on se ferait regarder de travers ?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Oui, on pourrait vraisemblablement être regardé de travers dans beaucoup de contextes. C'est acceptable entre amis, beaucoup moins en milieu professionnel. Mais la réponse de Jiliagre est meilleure.

Comment: Malgré cette grossièreté, cette réponse a l'avantage d'être plus générale et s'applique à toute action vaine et inutile, pas seulement au discours. J'emploie régulièrement cette expression ou d'autres aussi imagées dans le cadre professionnel et si effectivement je choisi les gens devant qui je parle ainsi, elle est quand-même assez facilement acceptée...

Comment: @LaurentS. "prêcher dans le désert", ça s'emploie aussi souvent ?

Comment: Oui effectivement. Je vous conseille de répondre de la sorte à votre propre question.

Answer (score 3):

En plus des deux très bonnes réponses déjà données, je rajouterais

> Ça rentre par une oreille et ça ressort par l'autre

Je pense que ça se passe d'explications...

Answer (score 1):

On peut égallement dire: [prêcher dans le désert](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%AAcher_dans_le_d%C3%A9sert), dans le sens

> Parler inutilement à des gens qui ne veulent pas se laisser convaincre.

Mais, finalement

> [Il n’est pire sourd que celui qui ne veut pas entendre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_n%E2%80%99est_pire_sourd_que_celui_qui_ne_veut_pas_entendre)

Answer (score 0):

Les autres réponses sont bonnes, mais assez générales pour quelque chose d'inutile, quelque soit la circonstance. Pourtant, on a un proverbe spécialement pour quand quelqu'un refuse d'écouter les conseils ou les arguments :

> On ne saurait faire boire un âne qui n’a pas soif ([source](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_ne_saurait_faire_boire_un_%C3%A2ne_qui_n%E2%80%99a_pas_soif))

Attention par contre, c'est un proverbe plus qu'une expression.